# How can i have same header of first page in rest of all the pages

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to know how can we get same header for all pages of print out which we got from the web browser, by using `window.print();`

i tried,

```
<td ><input  type="button" class="noPrint" onclick="window.print();" />
</td>
```

But its not giving the same header of 1st page in the rest of all the pages.

Edited :
            I mean to say, when print the content in my web page it came 3 pages, 1st page has some header. i want to get the same header in all my pages. how can i do that.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking currently.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking ? Please be more clear !

Comment: I'm understanding this as _"When a user prints out my website onto a piece of paper, at the top of each page I want it to have a banner/page header"_, and I'm thinking that this is almost impossibly difficult to achieve with a _HTML_ file.

Comment: Maybe helpful: [_CSS's_ `@media print` and `@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Getting_Started/Media) **edit** this link actually even includes exactly what you want

Comment: Yes , its good one @PaulS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tszt(Title,Grdid) {

        var url = window.document.URL;

        var sp = url.split("/");

        var web = "http://" + sp[2];

        var html_ = $(Grdid).parent().html();
        var alstring = "sss";
        html_ = html_.replace("<table", "<table rules=\"all\" border=\"1\" ");

        $(".Div_Msg").html("<div id=\"mws-validate-info\" class=\"mws-form-message info\" style=\"\"><b>Printing</b><br> Please wait..</div>");

        $.ajax({
            url: web + "/webmethods.aspx/CollagePrintingHeader",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'prefixText':'" + Title + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alstring = msg.d;

                var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());
                var jFrame = $("<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'>");
                jFrame
                .css("width", "1px")
                .css("height", "1px")
                .css("position", "absolute")
                .css("left", "-9999px")
                .appendTo($("body:first"))
                ;

                var objFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];

                var objDoc = objFrame.document;
                var jStyleDiv = $("<div>").append(
                    $("style").clone()
                    );

                objDoc.open();
                objDoc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
                objDoc.write("<html>");
                objDoc.write("<body>");
                objDoc.write("<head>");
                objDoc.write("<style> body{font-family:Arial;font-size:11px}");
                objDoc.write("</style>");
                objDoc.write("<title>");
                objDoc.write(document.title);
                objDoc.write("</title>");
                objDoc.write(jStyleDiv.html());
                objDoc.write("</head>");
                objDoc.write(alstring);

                objDoc.write(html_);

                objDoc.write("</body>");
                objDoc.write("</html>");
                objDoc.close();

                objFrame.focus();
                //window.open(objDoc.);
                objFrame.print();

                $(".Div_Msg").html("");
            },
            error: function () {
                $(".Div_Msg").html("<div id=\"mws-validate-ErrorMsg\" class=\"mws-form-message ErrorMsg\" style=\"\"><b>Error</b><br>Cant Print. Error Found in process.</div>");
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```